# PHP - Array Search Not Returning Anything

Tags: php, arrays

Currently working on a project in C but I have to generate a large struct which I figured would generate in PHP since I'm more familiar with PHP.

I have 2 arrays. The first one is quite simple (is way larger than this but I assume this is enough to replicate the issue):

```
$vehicles = [
    'vehicleSuper' => [ "adder", "autarch", "banshee2", "bullet"  ],
    'vehicleSport' => [ "alpha", "banshee", "bestiagts", "blista2" ],
    //...
];
```

The second array looks like this:

```
$textures = [
    'candc_apartments' => [
        "limo2_b", "limo2",
    ],
    'candc_default' => [
        "marshall_flag18_b", "mesa_b", "rentbus", "marshall_flag21_b", "crusader", "boxville4", "buzzard_b", "dukes2_b", "dukes",
    ],
    'lgm_default' => [
        "hotknife", "coquette", "voltic_tless", "vacca", "infernus", "cogcabri_b", "stinger_b", "banshee_b", "ztype", "ninef", "jb700", "superd", "monroe_b", "rapidgt2_b", "khamel", "comet2_b", "cheetah_b", "rapidgt_b", "stinger", "carbon_b", "surano_convertable_b", "rapidgt2", "infernus_b", "jb700_b", "ninef_b", "stingerg", "superd_b", "bullet_b", "ztype_b", "hotknife_b", "cogcabri", "surano_convertable", "rapidgt", "stingerg_b", "coquette_b", "bullet", "carbon", "ninef2", "carboniz", "cheetah", "adder_b", "entityxf", "adder", "feltzer",
    ],
];
```

Now I generate the list like this using the 2 arrays above:

```
echo '<pre>';

foreach($vehicles as $category => $val) {
    echo "vehicleSpawner " . $category . "[] = {\n";
    foreach($val as $item) {
        echo "  { \"" . $item . "\", \"" . array_search($item, array_column($textures, $item)) . "\", \"\" },\n";
    }
    echo '}';
echo '<hr>';
}
```

This outputs something similar to:

```
{ "adder", "", "" },
```

The last 2 values are empty. **What I want to achieve: Fill these out with the values from `$textures` array.** In this case, I'm trying to fill it up like this:

```
// arg 1: name from $vehicles
// arg 2: key from $textures
// arg 3: val from $textures
{ "adder", "lgm_default", "adder" },
```

Currently my `array_search($item, array_column($textures, $item))` method doesn't seem to work. How would I go and get this working? Help is appreciated, thanks all!

Comment: Why do you need to store redundant data? `adder` and `adder`?

Comment: @mickmackusa It's common for these values to be the same, but in rare cases they may differ from eachother.

Comment: If you are performing an `array_search()` they will be identical.  Would you rather something like this: https://3v4l.org/YCcIl ?  This compares the two subarrays just once and then iterates the matches versus performing a full search over and over.  Does my suggestion perform as required or am I misunderstanding your requirements?

Comment: @mickmackusa That is indeed what I was looking for, both answers work. This might be better for people who use the code in production environments, but since I only use the code to generate a list for myself, both answers are working fine in my case. Does your code ignore fields which do not have a value like `{ "adder", "", "" },`?

Comment: My code will not generate empty results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`array_column($textures, $item)` will search in array `$textures` key named `$item`, but there is no key with that name so it returns false, what you need to do is loop on `$textures` array and search if value `$item` exists:

```
foreach($val as $item) {
    foreach($textures as $k => $v) {
        //this will return array index or false if not exists
        $pos = array_search($item, $v);
        if ( $pos !== false )
            echo "  { \"" . $item . "\", \"" . $k . "\", \"".$v[$pos]."\" },\n";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to see multiple matches within a given pair of subarrays, `array_intersect()` will compare both subarrays once and iterate the results.  This is more efficient than running fresh `array_search()` calls for each element of one of the subarrays.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/YCcIl))

```
foreach($vehicles as $category => $v_vals) {
    echo "vehicleSpawner " . $category . "[] = {\n";
    foreach($textures as $k => $t_vals) {
        foreach (array_intersect($v_vals, $t_vals) as $match) {
            echo "  { \"$match\", \"$k\", \"$match\" },\n";
        }
    }
    echo "}\n";
}
```

Output:

```
vehicleSpawner vehicleSuper[] = {
  { "adder", "lgm_default", "adder" },
  { "bullet", "lgm_default", "bullet" },
}
vehicleSpawner vehicleSport[] = {
}
```

If this isn't the exact output format/structure that you desire, it can be tweaked to accommodate.

Comment: Is it possible to keep the full `$vehicles` array in the output, even when the `$textures` array does not contain these values with this code?

Comment: Sure.  I'm away from my computer now.  Back later.

Comment: Okay, I appreciate your help!

Comment: Always post your exact expected result when you post a question on this site.

Comment: Sorry, I figured I would be able to fix it myself but it seems it's quite hard to have the other *incomplete* values show up aswell. As mentioned I certainly do appreciate you trying to help me out as I've been struggling with this whole issue in general for quite some hours!

Comment: I've decided to remove the third parameter that you desire in the output because it is always a duplicate of the first (or when it is empty, that information is indicated by the second param).  https://3v4l.org/ABIQu  This solution generates a "lookup" array then employs `isset()` as a lightning fast tool to check for a match during iteration.  If you would like any further modification or explanation, just ask.

Comment: This is perfect, thanks a lot for all the help. Certainly very appreciated and helpful!

Comment: If you can generate `$textures` in the style/structure of `$lookup` to begin with, then you can skip the extra loop -- I don't know how your data is being generated.